# Visual Studio 2010 won't copy dependent dll from dependent project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dependencies, activemq-classic

The following picture shows an exceprt of the projects within my solution. When I build the Midas.Server project, only the Apache.NMS.dll is copied to the Release folder. Any suggestions why? Or how to force it? :(

[image]

Comment: It copies assemblies that are actually used in your code.  If you think the compiler gets this wrong then you'll have to copy it yourself with a post-build event.  Test your assumptions by removing that reference and rebuilding the project.

Comment: The missing one is the actual implementation of the above one, which is only the interface definition. So the code does not explicitly "use" it. Do you have an example how to copy it manually or another idea?

Comment: Just google it, "post build event copy" gives lots of hits.